# Random Background Image PHP

Tags: php, css

I am using the PHP code below to display a random header image every time a page is refreshed. This works fine but I need to add a specific background-position css property to some of the images.

For example headerimage3.jpg needs a background-position:20px and headerimage1.jpg needs a background-position:50px.

Is this possible using the PHP code below or will javascript need to be used?

```
<style type="text/css">
#header-image{background:url("/files/headerimage<?php echo rand(1,4)?>.jpg");background-position:center center;background-size:cover}}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add php header:

```
<?php
    $rnd = rand (1,4);
    $pos = ($rnd == 1) ? "50px 0;" : ($rnd == 3) ? "20px 0;" : "top left";
?>
```

then in css:

```
<style type="text/css">
#header-image
{
    background-image: url("/files/headerimage<?php echo $rnd ?>.jpg");
    background-position: <?php echo $pos ?>;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Is it possible to assign class to each image, so that the background-position can be set within the stylesheet rather than within the php header?

Comment: You can add a class name to the html element using php, for ex. `<div id="header-image" class="<?php echo image$rnd ?>"`, and then you can specify separate rule for each class.

Answer (score 0):

so one way is to pass a variable and check it to assign a new data:

```
<?php 
$rand=rand(1,4);
if ($rand==1){$back="50px";}
elseif ($rand==3){$back="20px";}
else{$back="center";}
?>
<style type="text/css">
#header-image{background:url("/files/headerimage<?php echo $rand; ?>.jpg");background-position:<?php echo $back;?> center;background-size:cover}}
</style
```