# php Setting background image randomly from folder

Tags: php, html, css, background-image

I am trying to randomly set the background image of a webpage from a folder via PHP.

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>404</title>
    </head>

    <body id="Background404">
        <p>404-Page not found. <a href="http://url.com>Home.</a></p>
    <?php
        $dir = '/var/www/html/Images';
        $fileNames = array();
        if(is_dir($dir)){
            $handle = opendir($dir);
            while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                if(is_file($dir.'/'.$file) && is_readable($dir.'/'.$file)){
                $fileNames[] = $file;
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
            $fileNames = array_reverse($fileNames);
            print_r($fileNames);
        }
        $totalLength = sizeof($fileNames);
        $randInt = rand(0, $totalLength);
        $randFile = $fileNames[$randInt];
        echo '<style> #Background404{background: url($randFile);}</style>';

    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Note: the printing of the files is just to ensure I reach that point in code and to see what the files are called. I found a similar question here: [Random Background Image PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462537/random-background-image-php) but when I used that answer I got just a pure white background.

Here is a copy of printed array:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => GraniteBridge.png
        [1] => mobileBackground.png
        [2] => OtherKingdom.png
        [3] => NetherBase.png
        [4] => BackgroundTablet.png
        [5] => Snowy.png
        [6] => Village.png
        [7] => background2.png
        [8] => CactusFarm.png
        [9] => FrontView.png
        [10] => CreditsPortal.png
        [11] => FrontNight.png
        [12] => background4.png
        [13] => XPFarmRailway.png
        [14] => GoldIronFarms.png
        [15] => Pyramid.png
        [16] => NetherFortress.png
        [17] => TheEnd.png
        [18] => Library.png
        [19] => Background.png
        [20] => twitter.png
        [21] => mobileBackground1.png
        [22] => mobileBackground2.png
        [23] => BirdsEyeView.png
        [24] => EndPortal.png
        [25] => AboveVillage.png
        [26] => TowerToTheHeavens.png
        [27] => TowerArmorStands.png
        [28] => FullSizeBackground.png
        [29] => Mansion.png
        [30] => Night.png
        [31] => Dojo.png
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_rand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to get a random index in the array. 
Then you can use that random index to get an image from your array

```
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
```

This is a complete example which uses [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to fetch the images in the folder

```
<?php 
$imagesDir = '/var/www/html/images';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
?>

<img style="background-image:url('/path/to/images/<?php echo $randomImage ?>');"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can see that elements in array are ordered ascending by they array key. We can use this information to create a proper approach for grabbing random array element.

First of all you have to grab the count of array so:

```
$count = count($fileNames);
```

Then just use rand() function to generate random number from 0 to the count of array:

```
$random = rand(0, $count) - 1;
```

Now you've got random array key so you can use it:

```
<img style="background-image:url('path/to/image/<?=$fileNames[$random]?>');"/>
```

Comment: I've just edited the post cause I did a misstake and didnt assign random value to variable for later use.

Comment: I've tried this and now I see an image element, but it doesn't find the image and when I copy the image address I get "http://96.19.31.19/var/www/html/Images/$fileNames[%3C?=$random?%3E]" so it's aparanetly not switching the php to plain text to use in the html

Comment: I added a "`- 1`" since the array is [zero-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering),otherwise it will produce an occasional error.  Also, personally I always use [`mt_rand`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) instead of [`rand`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php).  It's not a big deal either way for a task like this, but is generally preferred since it produces a "*[more random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister)"* number (but the syntax is identical to `rand`.)

Comment: Also you need the -1 within the parenthesis right now you're getting an int [-1, $count -1] where you want: `$random = rand(0, $count -1);`

Answer (score 1):

## Taking it a step further...

- this randomly chooses a **jpg**, **png** or **gif** image from the specified folder,
- displays the "entire" (`contain`ed) picture as the `background-image` (via the html `<body>` tag)
- set the page `background-color` to the **average color** of the image,
- shows the "short" filename of the background image in a `<div>`, and,
- sets the `<div>`'s text `color` to **Black** or **White**: whichever will best **contrast** the image colors.

```php
<html>
<?php
  // get array of image filenames (jpg/png/gif) from specified folder
  $img_path="../images/";
  $imgs=glob($img_path."*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);

  // choose an image randomly
  $rnd_img = $imgs[mt_rand(0, count($imgs)-1)];

  // calc average $r,$g,$b + recommended $text_color  
  extract(text_color_from_avg_img_color($rnd_img));

  // print html <body> tag with bg image + avg bg color
  echo "<body style=\"background: rgb($r,$g,$b) url('$rnd_img'); " 
      ."background-position:center; background-size:contain; "
      ."background-repeat:no-repeat; height:100%; \">";

  //print image title in appropriate color
  echo "<div style='color:$txt_color; font-size:5vmin;'>"
      ."Random image: '".basename($rnd_img)."'</div>";


  function text_color_from_avg_img_color( $fname ) {
  /* adapted from gist.github.com/8098215 + stackoverflow.com/q/1331591 */  
    try  {  $image = new Imagick($fname); //uses Imagick to...
          $image->scaleimage(1, 1);  // scale to 1x1 pixel to get avg color
          if(!$pixels = $image->getimagehistogram())  { return 'black'; }
        } catch(ImagickException $e)                  { return 'black'; }
          catch(Exception $e)                         { return 'black'; }
    extract(reset($pixels)->getcolor()); //next calc best contrast color: 
    $L=0.2126*pow($r/255,2.2)+0.7152*pow($g/255,2.2)+0.0722*pow($b/255,2.2);
    $txt_color=((int)($L>0?(($L+0.05)/0.05):(0.05/($L+0.05)))>5?'black':'white');
    return compact("txt_color", "r", "g", "b");  //return array
  }
```

Comment: Heh nice, can't say I need this code anymore and it's interesting to see how simple my questions were 3 years ago, but your answer is the most complete. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake here is the original code working as intended.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>404</title>
    </head>

    <body id="Background404">
        <p>404-Page not found. <a href="http://url.com">Home.</a></p>
    <?php
        $dir = './images';
        $fileNames = array();
        if(is_dir($dir)){
            $handle = opendir($dir);
            while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                if(is_file($dir.'/'.$file) && is_readable($dir.'/'.$file)){
                    $fileNames[] = $file;
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
            $fileNames = array_reverse($fileNames);
            print_r($fileNames);
        }
        $totalLength = count($fileNames);
        $randInt = rand(0, $totalLength -1);
        $randFile = $fileNames[$randInt];
        echo $randFile;
        echo "<style> #Background404{background: url('./images/$randFile');}</style>";
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Switched from using `sizeof($fileNames)` to `count($fileNames)` to avoid confusion coming from other languages expecting `sizeof` to return allocated memory size.

Add complete path as `$fileNames` just contains the file name where html expects a  path from webroot.

Add `-1` to end of rand range to ensure a valid index is retrieved.

Switch single quotes to double quotes so variable would be output properly